# starting out with jquery templates issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I have: jquery1.6.min, jquery-tmpl.js (latest beta) and knockout-1.2.0.js. I am using a very simple example but I cannot get jquery templates to render, I cannot figure out why, simply put I can see the elements in the dom by scanning the dom using firebug - I have some tmp=annonymous(jquery,$item) appearing but the data does not render inside the dom.

template:

```
<script id="bookTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <h2>${title}</h2>
    price: ${formatPrice(price)}
</script>
```

jscode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // Create an array of books
        var books = [
            { title: "ASP.NET 4 Unleashed", price: 37.79 },
            { title: "ASP.NET MVC Unleashed", price: 44.99 },
            { title: "ASP.NET Kick Start", price: 4.00 },
            { title: "ASP.NET MVC Unleashed iPhone", price: 44.99}];

        function formatPrice(price) {
            return "$" + price.toFixed(2);
        }

        // Render the books using the template
        $('#bookTemplate').tmpl(books).appendTo('#bookContainer');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.formatPrice = function formatPrice(price) {
    return "$" + price.toFixed(2);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yjbfr/1/)

Your calling `formatPrice` in your template but defining the function in your closure. To be able to do this `formatPrice` has to be in global scope. An easy way to do this is to assign the function to `windiw.formatPrice`

Comment: I feel like a total idiot... what you showed me helped me, but I missed out adding the actual container i was appending to: '<div id="bookContainer"></div>'

Comment: @Haroon Oh. I assumed you had that in your HTML :D If it solved your problem accept it :)

Comment: I had to wait 4 minutes for some reason, will do. Thank you :)